# Undefined behaviour of delete operator

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I am relatively new to C++ and I'm learning about pointers. I was trying to dynamically allocate some memory for an array and found this issue.

Here is my code,

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int n = 5;
    int *arr = new int(n*(sizeof(int)));

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        *(arr+i) = i+1;

    delete[] arr;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        std::cout << *(arr+i) << " ";
}
```

and the expected output is some garbage value since I'm freeing the memory with delete operator, however, this is my output instead:

First run:
`755597344 47626 2043 4 5`

Second run:
`-1437908960 62859 2043 4 5`

Third run:
`-902037472 965 2043 4 5`

I've tried several runs, but only first 3 values change, and the others seem as the array was still there, what could be the explanation for this?

Comment: `new int(n*(sizeof(int)))` create *one **single*** `int` value, and initializes it to `(n*(sizeof(int)))`. I assume you really wanted `new int[n]`? (Which should be paired with a `delete[]`) It seems like you skipped some chapters from your C++ text books.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and the `*sizeof(int)` isn't necessary either, the compiler will figure out the number of actual bytes required.

Comment: On an unrelated note, for ant pointer or array `arr` and index `i`, the expression `*(arr + i)` is *exactly* equal to `arr[i]`. The latter is easier to read, understand as well as less to write.

Comment: Furthermore, once you have deallocated memory (with `delete` or `delete[]`) the pointer becomes invalid and you're not allowed to dereference it anymore. So you have multiple problems in that little piece of code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you really should take the extra few seconds to make that an actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the small piece of code there are multiple errors and problems:

- The expression `new int(n*(sizeof(int)))` allocates a *single* `int` value and initializes it to the value `n*(sizeof(int))`.

  If you want to allocate space for an array of `int` values you need to use `new[]`, as in `new int[n]`
- Because of the above problem, you will go *out of bounds* of the allocated memory, leading to *undefined behavior*.
- Once you fix issue number 1, you need to pair `new[]` with the `delete[]` operator. Mismatching operators also leads to *undefined behavior*.
- And lastly, once you have deleted memory you can no longer access it, and any attempt of dereferencing the pointer will again lead to *undefined behavior*.

All in all the program should look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    constexpr std::size_t n = 5;

    // Allocate memory
    int* arr = new[n];

    // Initialize the memory
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // Display the memory
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "arr[" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << '\n';
    }

    // Free the memory
    delete[] arr;
}
```

---

With all of the above said and done, there are better ways to create arrays of either fixed or dynamic size.

If you have a fixed-size array, whose size is known at compile-time and whose size will never change during run-time, use `std::array` instead:

```
// Create and initialize array
std::array<int, 5> arr = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }};

// Display array
for (int value : arr)
{
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

If the size is not known at compile-time, or the size will need to change during run-time, use `std::vector` instead:

```
// Create a vector with five "zero-initialized" elements
std::vector<int> arr(5);
```

Comment: Note that *undefined behavior* really means anything could happen, including having the program look like it's working.

Comment: alright, I get it now, Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
new int(n*(sizeof(int)));
```

This allocates only single int and set value as `n*(sizeof(int))`.

If you want array of int, you have to do like below.

```
   int *arr = new int[n];
```